# Как дебажить код LESS?

Tags: less

Привет.

Как проверить код LESS на ошибки? Полдела - правильный редактор кода?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавьте перед подключением less js такую строку:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>less = { env: 'development' };</script>
```

Comment: Шикарный прием....Благодарен

Answer (score 0):

Если использовать какой-либо компилятор, то он обычно тоже выводит все сообщения об ошибках - консольный (например, grunt-contrib-less), встроенный (webStorm, phpStorm) или программный (Crunch, Coala, WinLess).

К слову, все-таки лучше компилировать less локально при верстке.